# Firefox menu bar is not visible when hovering in full screen mode

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-unity, firefox-quantum

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and then I installed Firefox 59 on it.

Now the problem I'm having is , Firefox does not show the menu bar when I hover the title of the webpage.

For other applications (Gedit,Termainal) the default behavior is there.

But As I remember this was the default behavior in my Firefox 49 and Ubuntu 14 versions.

Do I need to enable any configuration to make this work ???

I don't want to show the Menu bar permanently by enabling it via Firefox customization.